# How to turn a matrix into a 'function'?

Tags: functions, matrix, replacement, assignment

I have some codes to turn a set of equations into a matrix. Suppose the matrix `L`is expressed in terms of variables $\epsilon$, $K$, $M$, and I want to make a function which takes the numerical values of $\epsilon$, $K$, $M$ and return the matrix `L` in numerical form. How should I do it? I know I can use replacement like `L/.{M->1,epsilon->0.1,K->10}`, but I think having `L[0.1,10,1]` will make the subsequent codes look nicer.

Edit:

I generate `L` as follow:

I use DSolve to find the general solutions of a few vriables in terms of the constants `C[1]`, `C[2]`, `C[3]`, etc. Then I define the equations I'm solving:

`eq1=Simplify[...]`, and extract the coefficient of each underdetermined constants `row1=Map[Simplify,Table[Coefficient[Substract@@eq1,C[n]],{n,1,5}]]`. Finally, I construct the matrix for the linear system of equations as `L={row1,row2,row3...}`.

Comment: You may also try  `L1[e1_, k1_, m1_] := With[{e1=e1,k1=k1,m1=m1},L]`.  Might be a bit faster than approaches based on `ReplaceAll`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some more code/examples would help to understand better what you need, but one (not very elegant) solution might be:

```
L1[e1_, k1_, m1_] := L /. {e -> e1, k -> k1, m -> m1}
```

For a nice solution, I'd probably look into making L a function from the start, but as you didn't provide details about how you generate/define it it is hard to help you with that.